# What is the difference between as_json vs JSON.parse?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could someone please specify difference between `as_json` and `JSON.parse`?
The only difference is that `JSON.parse` part of Ruby Standard Library and `as_json` part of Rails ActiveSupport?

Rails console:

```
irb(main):001:0> json_str = "{\"foo\": {\"bar\": 1, \"baz\": 2}, \"bat\": [0, 1, 2]}"
irb(main):002:0> puts JSON.parse(json_str)
{"foo"=>{"bar"=>1, "baz"=>2}, "bat"=>[0, 1, 2]}
irb(main):003:0> puts json_str.as_json
{"foo": {"bar": 1, "baz": 2}, "bat": [0, 1, 2]}
```

Ref:

- https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON/Ext/Parser.html#method-i-parse
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two methods are in some sense exact opposites of each other:

- [`JSON.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) parses a Ruby `String` containing a JSON Document into a Ruby object corresponding to the JSON Value described by the JSON document. So, it goes *from JSON to Ruby*.
- `as_json` returns a *simplified representation* of a complex Ruby object that uses only Ruby types that can be easily represented as JSON Values. In other words, it turns an arbitrarily complex Ruby object into a Ruby object that uses only `Hash`, `Array`, `String`, `Integer`, `Float`, `true`, `false`, and `nil` which correspond to the JSON types *object* (really a dictionary), *array*, *string*, *number*, *boolean*, and *null*. The intent is that you can then easily serialize this simplified representation to JSON. So, `as_json` goes *from Ruby (halfway) to JSON*. In other words, the opposite direction from `JSON.parse`.

Apart from operating in opposite directions, there are some minor other differences as well:

- `JSON.parse` is a *concrete method*, whereas `as_json` is an abstract *protocol* that is implemented by many different kinds of objects. (Similar to e.g. `each` in Ruby).
- `JSON.parse` is part of the Ruby standard library (but not the core library, more precisely, it is part of the `json` gem, which is a *default gem*). The `as_json` protocol is defined by `ActiveRecord`'s `Serializers` API, i.e. it is part of `ActiveRecord`, not Ruby.

So, why does `as_json` exist in the first place? Why this two-step process of converting complex Ruby objects to simpler Ruby objects and then to a JSON Document instead of going straight from complex Ruby objects to a JSON Document? Well, if you have complex Ruby objects, chances are, that no object actually fully knows how to serialize itself as a JSON Document. It has to first ask its constituent objects to serialize themselves, and then stitch it all together, and this applies recursively to the constituent objects as well. With all this stitching together of JSON Documents, there is a real risk of producing an invalid JSON Document or double-encoding some part of it, or something along that lines.

Basically, once you have serialized something to a JSON Document, then all you have is a `String` and all you can do is `String` manipulation. Whereas, if you have a richer Ruby object like `Hash`, `Array`, `Integer`, etc., then you can use that object's methods as well. Imagine, for example, having to merge two JSON Documents containing JSON Objects *as a `String`* compared to simply merging two Ruby `Hash`es.

So, the idea is to use `as_json` *first* to create a Ruby object that is simpler and less powerful than the original, but still much more powerful than a simple `String`. And only once you have assembled the entire thing, do you use `to_json` to serialize it to a JSON Document. (Or rather, the serialization framework does that for you.)

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` parses a json string.

`.as_json` is a serialization method available to all data types, not just strings.

E.g. from the ruby docs:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.as_json
# => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#     "created_at" => "2006-08-01T17:27:133.000Z", "awesome" => true}
```

But `JSON.parse` won't handle that:

```
user = User.find(1)
JSON.parse(user)
--> no implicit conversion of User into String (TypeError)
```

Edit

Edited based on comment from @Jorg.

`JSON.parse` does not return specifically a `Hash`.

Comment: "`JSON.parse` parses a json string into a ruby hash" – That's not true. For example, `JSON.parse('1')` does not return a `Hash`, nor does `JSON.parse('[]')` or `JSON.parse('""')` or `JSON.parse('true')` or `JSON.parse('null')`.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` parses the given JSON string and converts it to an Object,While the as_json Returns a hash representing the model.

```
user = User.first
user.as_json

=> {"id"=>1, "email"=>"fa18-bcs-215@cuilahore.edu.pk", 
"name"=>"Noman", "user_type"=>"Manager"}
```

and if we apply `as_json` to string it simple return that string

```
json_str = "{\"foo\": {\"bar\": 1, \"baz\": 2}, \"bat\": [0, 1, 2]}"
json_str.as_json

=> "{\"foo\": {\"bar\": 1, \"baz\": 2}, \"bat\": [0, 1, 2]}"
```

if we apply `JSON.parse()` to string it returns hash.

```
JSON.parse(json_str)
=> {"foo"=>{"bar"=>1, "baz"=>2}, "bat"=>[0, 1, 2]}
```